# Problem SAP Successfactors Non-Standard OCN Provider Integration (duration parameters)

Tags: sap-successfactors

I'm working on an integration project connecting SAP Successfactors with a Non-Standard OCN Provider, I am using the API used by SuccessFactors

```
...
"program":[
{
"startDate": 1451556622000,
"endDate": 1427796622000,
"active": true,
"duration": "12 weeks"
}
],
"revisionNumber": 1,
"duration": "18 minutes"
...
```

The web service reports that everything is correct. But I fail to visualize the duration parameters. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The process is correcta, the info is in:

Viewing Open Content Network Sessions.

1. Go to SAP SuccessFactors Learning and then go to Learning  Items.
2. Find and open the learning item that you want to check.
3. Go to Related  More  Content Network Sessions.

Ciao